# Downloading Ubuntu to Computer with No OS

Tags: installation, dvd

I recently got back my computer from a hard drive breakdown.  I got back the computer with everything except an operating system.  I was hoping to be able to download Ubuntu to at least have an operating system, but after burning Ubuntu to a DVD, my computer will not recognize an operating system on the DVD.  What do I need to do differently/add to the DVD to make things work?

Comment: Hello Mitchell, Welcome to AskUbuntu. Did you already check your BIOS Setup in order to check if the computer is attempting to boot from CD/DVD? Please check it on your BIOS and if needed change the BOOT order. Please let us know the brand name/model of your computer, which release are you trying to install and if it is a 32 or 64 bit version in order to get the best support for you.

Comment: Don't be insulted, but did you burn the .iso to a DVD as a file, or did you burn the .iso to a DVD as a reincarnation of the original Ubuntu install disk with a all the files necessary to boot into Ubuntu? They're not the same thing at all, and I've met several reasonable people who did not know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply placing the .ISO file onto the disc the computer will not recognize it as bootable and you must therefore use a program like [imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/) to "write image file to disk" which will then extract the contents to the disc rather than place the ISO on the disc. Then you can resume as usual and boot to the disc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with what both devs suggested, reburn the iso as a filesystem, simple as using imgburn and set your BIOS settings so your DVD/CD drive is the first that boots up.